# Can you win Gamer Mom?

Tags: gamer-mom

In [*Gamer Mom*](http://adventure.gamism.org/gamer_mom/#) is it possible to convince at least one member of your family to play with you? How?

Comment: This game is extremely depressing

Comment: @BenBrocka: And you probably haven't even started reading the source code yet.

Comment: Oh wow. The source code (js) is at http://adventure.gamism.org/gamer_mom/gm.js if anyone was wondering, it's well commented too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've been looking through the source code of this game for a while now, and I think I've found out how to beat the game, although it's probably not what you're expecting.  There may not even be a true way to 'win', just various different endings.  Spoiler alert:

> In order to "beat" the game, no one else in the family will actually play WoW.  The mom will just think that she's persuaded the father, and will leave the table happily (when in fact no one may really be interested).

Here is the process:

> 1. ...it might just fix everything!
> 2. go for it
> 3. Repeat
> 4. Continue
> 5. this could work
> 6. Introduction
> 7. Chapter 1: My Friends
> 8. Rethink approach
> 9. Engage them in chitchat
> 10. School (x4)
> 11. Work (x2)
> 12. i think it might be safe to ask
> 13. I'll just ask.
> 14. Be Subtle
> 15. They need more fun
> 16. Give up
> 17. He's Interested! (x2)
> 18. Set up the game
> 19. <3 (x2)
> 20. Set up the game
> 21. <3

You can, in fact, get the dad to play (which if I think may be what you are actually asking, forgive the above), but his phone will ring and he will leave the game no matter what you do:

> 1. ...it might just fix everything!
> 2. go for it
> 3. Repeat
> 4. Continue
> 5. this could work
> 6. Introduction
> 7. Chapter 1: My Friends
> 8. Rethink approach
> 9. i think it might be safe to ask
> 10. I'll just ask.
> 11. Go all in
> 12. Present the vision
> 13. Don't slow down!
> 14. "big"
> 15. We'll start on Thursday
> 16. Get out now
> 17. Run!
> 18. Avoid them until Thursday

After this point, no matter what you do, the dad's phone will ring eventually and he will get up and leave.

The author of the game left a lot of comments (some very personal) in the [javascript code](http://adventure.gamism.org/gamer_mom/gm.js) of the game, almost like diary entries.  The quote he left when you get the "heart" ending of the game is what led me to believe it's the game-winning ending:

> /*Kyler entirely changed the meaning of this ending: I had intended it
>   as one of the most depressing endings, and he turned it into the most
>   hopeful. The way I pictured it, the husband and daughter are just
>   stunned at her sudden energy. The running, the whisper and the kiss
>   all seem from their perspective to be coming from out of nowhere. So
>   there would be this dissonance between an adorably cute little
>   heart-button, and the visual of them holding blank expressions on
>   their faces. She runs out of the room thinking she's managed to pull
>   the family together, and actually no such thing has happened. But
>   Kyler chose to take the cuteness at face value, and I'm not arguing
>   with him because it's a valid interpretation and god knows the game
>   could use some cheering up. As an amateur actor myself, I respect the
>   pursuit of personal interpretations. Maybe there's hope for this
>   family after all! */

Answer (score 1):

I haven't managed it yet. I've been playing for ages...it's really irritating.

I almost got the husband to play once, but then the daughter told him not to give in to my "crazy" demands.

I've taken to just smacking the husband repeatedly since I can't win.

Comment: I believe it is supposed to be possible though.

Comment: do you remember your approach to get the husband to play?  I have a feeling you need both approaches to win.

Comment: Be wary of the ending where it sounds like you'll get the husband to play, but in the end you just run off leaving him baffled. (You'll recognize it as ♥.)

Comment: It is possible according to the code... `In case you were wondering: this is not a trick puzzle. There is a way to get them to play.` Found in the HTML, dunno how to actually get it to happen

Comment: I had that `In case you were wondering` pop up after a few tries of playing (around 5 in a row).

Answer (score 1):

Skip all the small talk, go all in, pitch the big vision, wait til next Thursday, and avoid them til then.

Comment: Do you have a more specific list of choices to make? I wasn't sure which choices to make at a couple points with this advice and couldn't get them to play

Comment: Yes, I do, but I think it spoils it to give the answer explicitly as a set of steps.  You need to ignore the main small talk and just click "I think it might be safe to ask" and don't lose any momentum.

Comment: Not losing momentum just leads to "stop acting crazy" and another failure

Comment: That means you've picked options aside from the main track. You need to click 'I think it might be safe to ask' immediately. Then, ignore every possible option not related to plunging forward. Use "Don't slow down" and "We'll start on Thursday."

Comment: oh wow, this totally worked.  But I can't figure out how to keep him playing.